# Proof of the surface area of a cone doesn't make sense (to me at least)

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, area, pi

Even though the surface area of a cone is $(\pi R G + \pi R^2)$, it makes sense to think that it actually is $\pi R\times \text{Height} + \pi R^2$ as you could think that the side area $=$ average circumference $\times$ height instead of being average circumference $\times$ generatrix ??? Is there something I'm missing?

R $:=$ Radius of the base and
G $:=$ The cone's generatrix

Comment: Your first formula is wrong. The second term does not even have the dimension of an area.

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: The proof of area of curved surface of cone is not difficult. Just cut open the cone along a generatrix and the curved surface turns into a sector of circle with radius $G$ and arc length of sector is $2\pi R$. Hence the area is $(1/2)G(2\pi R) =\pi RG$. Here is average height is actually $G$ and not $H$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh I don't think you understood my question. I know its proof, however, I don't know why πR×Height+πR2 doesn't work in an algebraically proven way. I know you can use monte carlo  simulations ,etc, but I'm not looking for that kind of demonstration.

Comment: As I said in my comment height in this case is $G$. The formula of area as half of product of base and height applies to two dimensional triangles and when we try to put the cone on a plane by cutting it out the height is $G$.

Answer (score 0):

The formula (avg circumference)x(height) does not account for the slantedness of the surface.

Here's how to interpret your formula. While the cone is the surface of rotation for a diagonal line, suppose we instead rotated a "staircase" function (as in a Riemann sum for the diagonal line)  around the $x$-axis, and we thus get a bunch of disjoint thin cylinders (say, inside) the cone. As the number of pieces tends to infinity and their sizes tend to zero, the total surface area tends to (avg circumference)xheight.

Consider the lower-dimensional version of this: does the staircase function do good as an approximation for the length of a diagonal line? Of course not; it fails to account for the slantedness.

Imagine on the other hand cutting up the actual cone into pieces. Each piece's surface area can be approximated by a flat, non-slanted thin cylindrical piece with the same generatrix length; we can get an over-approximation using the larger circumference and an under-approximation using the smaller circumference of the conical piece. Putting all the over/under approximations together gives nice bounds, and then taking the limit gives (avg circumference)x(generatrix).

Comment: I understand the argument for using the generatrix but I don't get the argument against using the height.

Comment: @DAVID Consider [this picture](https://i.imgur.com/NzkrSDP.png). The total length of the red lines will not be a good approximation for the length of the black diagonal line. And yet, if you rotate this to get a black cone, your formula calculates the total surface area of the red thin cylinders - why would you think that's a good approximation? There isn't any good reason. Indeed, the fact the total length of the red line are off by a multiplicative factor means we have solid reason to expect it *doesn't* function as a good approximation.

Comment: @runaway What do the red lines have to do with the height?

Comment: My cone is sideways, so the "height" of the cone is horizontal.