# When is an approximation model correct in calculus?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I set myself the task of finding the surface area of a cone using calculus. One way to model the cone's surface area is as a series of cylinders, ascending in radius from the apex to the base. With this model, we can derive the surface area of the cone as $\pi r h$ (excluding its base). But this result is wrong, ultimately because the "cylinder stack" model is a bad approximation.

Another way to model the cone is as a "triangle strip", with the triangles joined at the apex. With this model, we can derive the surface area $\pi r \sqrt{h^2 + r^2}$ (again excluding its base). This is the accepted correct formula.

I have read arguments for why the "cylinder stack" model does not approximate the cone's surface area. For example, it ["does not account for the slantedness of the surface."](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3650314/116875) This makes sense. But my question is the inverse: **why should I trust that the accepted "triangle strip" model is correct?** How do we know that there isn't another way to model the cone that gives a different, more accurate formula for its surface area?

I want a formal test I can use, such that the "triangle strip" passes the test, and the "cylinder stack" model fails it. And I want this test to generalize to other shapes. Say I have some crazy teapot shape in mind, and come up with an approximation of it with triangles and  cylinders -- how do I know that my model is correct in the limit, e.g. that it "accounts for the slantedness" everywhere?

Comment: This question is confusing or doesn't make sense.  You describe two methods for calculating the side area of a cone, and point to a well-understood and -accepted explanation for why one method is invalid.  The reason you should accept the "triangle strip" method is that it covers *all* the area.  If your question is instead extremely broad, viz., "how do I know I'm not making a mistake...?" well... that's a far far larger question.  • If you said that either "2+2=5" or "2+2=4" and someone pointed out why "2+2=5" is incorrect, would your question actually be "but how do I know 2+2=4?"?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but perhaps it may be useful to know that the arc length of a (rectifiable) curve is _defined_ as the sum of lengths of line segments across it in the limit of very small, close-together lines -- not a stair-step model. Perhaps this gives some intuition as to why slanted lines help model 'surface effects'.

Comment: @RaadShaikh thanks, I think you've found the core problem: I don't have a precise definition of "surface area"! [Wikipedia has some discussion on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_area), and I just discovered the [Schwarz lantern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lantern), which seems to show how hard/subtle this problem is ...

Comment: @jameshfisher I had not heard about the difficulties in defining surface area before - thanks for pointing out this example!